# Apigee console error for instagram

Tags: instagram-api, apigee

Due to some recent changes in Instagram API policy, looks like now we can not use apigee console to check the API calls. I keep getting this error when I select OAuth2 for authentication and choose to sign into Instagram. 
"{"code": 403, "error_type": "OAuthForbiddenException", "error_message": "You are not a sandbox user of this client"}"

Anyone facing similar issues and knows any workaround for the same

Comment: Facing the same issue, I'm guessing apigee won't work in the future unless they get a rep from Instagram to special whitelist their app. I recommend making your own sandbox app to make your own test calls.

Comment: Yeah I'm totally "bummed" by this. Makes it more difficult for me to make test calls. And I have a sandbox app.... Anyone got an update? I am using a third party script (instafeed.js) and I want to move away from it as it's causing some scripting conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Its likely that this will never work, since the only way it will work is if Instagram allow apigee to use their 'sandbox' outside of instagrams 'sandbox' mode.

As per this thread;
https://community.apigee.com/questions/26922/instagram-oauth-failed.html